# How to send https request from Angular 6 to node.js

Tags: angular, nginx, https, mean, cloudflare

I have MEAN stack app where angular built in public folder of express,for running server on the same port.I have certificate from cloudflare added to node.js(for https server),also I run my server on nginx.I opened 443 port on ec2 and on nginx my server running with https.So problem is,that every time when I'm sending request to my app,it brings this problem

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain.ext/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://localhost:5000/'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Sometimes it sending requests, sometimes not. I tried different ways to send requests from angular and all of them I did with HttpClient,but urls are different

- "https://mydomain.ext/user/register"

  - "/user/register".

The point is that I need to send request with https from angular.Thanks for attention and thanks for help.

Comment: They need to be both either HTTPS, or both HTTP

Comment: user184994 I know that they must be https or http,now I need on https,how I can send https from Angular that built in public and running on same port with express server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just forgot to change in component.html file the url of button to https.This small issue takes 2 and half hour from my time. For someone else,I just can tell to check urls to change all of them to https.